# need SQL help, Find names of all departments whose professors collectively teach less than 3 courses

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Tables:

- department (dept_id, dept_name)
- student (student_id, student_name, major, level, age)
- professor (prof_id, prof_name, dept_id)
- course (course_code, name)
- semester_course (course_code, quarter, year, prof_id)
- enrolled (student_id, course_code, quarter, year, enrolled_at)

the question is Find names of all departments whose professors collectively teach less than
3 courses

my query right now looks like

```
select d.dept_name,d.dept_id FROM department as d 
WHERE d.dept_id in ( 
select d1.dept_id from department d1,professor p1 
where p1.dept_id = d1.dept_id AND p1.prof_id IN ( 
  select p2.prof_id from professor p2,semester_course sc
  WHERE sc.prof_id = p2.prof_id GROUP BY sc.course_code having count(*) < 3
) );
```

and it brings back wrong results, any help?

Comment: Please learn to use ANSI JOIN instead of cross products. It makes queries much easier to read and write.

Comment: You shouldn't be grouping by course code. That's counting the number of professors per course, not the number of courses taught by professors.

Comment: You need to get the number of courses taught, grouped by department.

Comment: so i tried GROUP BY p2.prof_id having count(*) < 3 and it still didn't work, i got alittle confused by your comment can you show me an example query maybe ? @Barmar

Comment: Read the assignment again: "departments whose professors collectively teach less than 3 courses". So you need `COUNT(DISTINCT course_id)` and `GROUP BY dept_id`.

Comment: please bare with me :) 
so this is my query now 


select DISTINCT d.dept_name FROM department as d,semester_course as sc, professor as p 
where p.dept_id = d.dept_id and p.prof_id IN (
    select p1.prof_id from professor p1, semester_course sc1
    where sc1.prof_id = p1.prof_id 
     GROUP BY p1.dept_id )


i dont exactly see how i can get the count of courses for each professor to be less than 3
@Barmar

Comment: You're misunderstanding the question.  It's not really about the professors, but about the departments.  Departments have professors that teach courses.  For the moment, let's just say the departments are teaching courses.  Find the list of departments that are teaching less than 3 courses.  That's what the word "collectively" means in this case.

Comment: This is unrelated but _"please **bare** with me"_ is just wrong.. It suppose to be _"please **bear** with me"_ .

Answer (score 0):

You should join all three tables, `department`, `professor`, and `semester_course`. Since the question asks about the count of courses per department, you should use `GROUP BY d.dept_id` and `COUNT(DISTINCT sc.course_code)` to implement the criteria that they want.

```
SELECT d.dept_name
FROM department as d
JOIN professor AS p ON p.dept_id = d.dept_id
JOIN semester_course AS sc ON sc.prof_id = p.prof_id
GROUP BY d.dept_id 
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT sc.course_code) < 3
```